# Why do I get an error while using requests module within a function with threads?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to learn multithreading, also new to coding python, trying to port a temperamental php script...

When I run this I get error:
`Unhandled exception in thread started by <function getthis at 0x7f2156dbb0c8>`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import thread
import time
import sys, requests, json, urllib2

def getthis( ticker ):
   x = requests.get("http://google.com/" + ticker)
   print x
   return


# Define a function for the thread
def print_time( threadName, delay):
   count = 0
   while count < 5:
      time.sleep(delay)
      count += 1
      print "%s: %s" % ( threadName, time.ctime(time.time()) )

# Create two threads as follows
try:
   thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread-1", 0, ) )
   thread.start_new_thread( getthis, ("AAPL", ) )
except:
       print "Error: unable to start thread"

while 1:
   pass
```

When I run the `getthis` function alone it works fine, I think I'm calling it wrong in the `thread.start`? Please help

Comment: No exception on my side. Running your code give me this output: 'Thread-1: Sat Apr 18 22:49:36 2015
Thread-1: Sat Apr 18 22:49:36 2015
Thread-1: Sat Apr 18 22:49:36 2015
Thread-1: Sat Apr 18 22:49:36 2015
Thread-1: Sat Apr 18 22:49:36 2015
<Response [404]>'

Comment: It seems the code was being cache'd some how, weird, when I changed the file name it was okay, very odd